# Twisted: deferred that fires repeatedly?

Tags: python, multithreading, callback, twisted

`Deferred`s are a great way to do asynchronous processing in Twisted. However, they, like the name implies, are for deferred computations, which only run and terminate once, firing the callbacks once. What if I have a repeated computation, like a button being clicked? Is there any `Deferred`-like object that can fire repeatedly, calling all callbacks attached to it whenever it is fired?

Comment: It's literally been four years, but someone gave me a very satisfactory [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27996359/2419669).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've set this up for now. For my limited use case it does what I want.

```
class RepeatedDeferred:
    def __init__(self):
        self.callbacks = []

        self.df = defer.Deferred()

    def addCallback(self, callback):
        self.callbacks.append(callback)

        self.df.addCallback(callback)

    def callback(self, res):
        self.df.callback(res)

        self.df = defer.Deferred()
        for c in self.callbacks:
            self.df.addCallback(c)
```

Someone let me know if this is terrible.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is [`defer.inlineCallbacks`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.1.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.html#inlineCallbacks) which allows you to use a generator to create a sequential chain of Deferreds.  Essentially you could just create a generator that never ends (or ends conditionally) and keep generating Deferreds from that.

There is a great writeup on using `inlineCallbacks` at [krondo.com](http://krondo.com/?p=2441).

Comment: heh awesome feature. reminds me of monads in Haskell, kinda. i don't think it's what I'm looking for, though. i'll think about it more when its not so late